# how to capture json returned value in php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm writing a script to make an api call and add credit card to a billing system

```
 <?php
   include 'class.hbwrapper.php';
   HBWrapper::setAPI('http://my-site.com/admin/api.php','API ID','API Key');
   $params = array(
      'id'=>ID,
      'cardnum'=>CARDNUM,
      'cardtype'=>CARDTYPE,
      'expiryyear'=>EXPIRYYEAR,
      'expirymonth'=>EXPIRYMONTH
   );
   $return = HBWrapper::singleton()->editClientCreditCard($params);
   print_r($return);
?>
```

Here is the response

```
  {
      "success": true,
      "call": "editClientCreditCard",
      "server_time": 1317726229,
      "info": [
         "Credit Card details updated"
      ]
   }
```

How can I write an if statement to check the value of returned success value if it is either true or false in php?

in another question, should I be looking at php to do this? or use jquery?

Thank you

Comment: Is the `$return` value a JSON string or an object?

Comment: have you looked at [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: I really scares me when people work with credit card data and don't even know how to work with json.

Comment: We all got to start somewhere ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your PHP version:

For an object:

```
if(json_decode($return)->success === true)
```

For an array:

```
if(json_decode($return, true)['success'] === true)
```

For older PHP or if you need the entire object/array decoded:

```
$result = json_decode($return);
if($result->success === true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this;

```
$data = json_decode($return); 

if($data['success'] === true) {

  //true

} else {

 //false 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **json_decode** to transform the JSON response to a php variable. Then you can check the response.

For further information look at the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$data=json_decode($your_json_string);
if($data->success){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this .

```
$return = json_decode($return);

if($return->success){
    // true
      echo "TRUE";

} else {
     // false
      echo "FALSE";
}
```